# Uncaught TypeError: n.auth is not a function (Angular Firebase App)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

My Angular app runs locally with no error, but when I build it and use:

```
firebase init hosting
```

```
firebase deploy
```

It gets deployed, but loads only the index, without any of my components and throws this error:

[image]

I searched a lot online, but there are not many solutions avaialable and none work. I tried adding:

```
"aot": true
```

in the configurations object in angular.json, as it was pointed out as a solution, but it did not help.

This is part of my app.module.ts :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZHGe.png)
I tried removing node modules and reinstalling them, as well as packet-lock.json, but nothing works.

These are my dependecies:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3h0R.png)

I was wondering if @angular/fire, which is ^7.6.1 could be causing this, but when I tried to install latest there were dependency peer issues and I couldn't. I tried with

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

But got mixed up in some errors and warnings, I'll try doing it the same, but this error keeps reappearing. Please help, I am not an expert, but more of a proffesional hobby enthusiast.

P.S.
The navigation on my page is visible, and when I click on one of the links, nothing changes on the page, but the console throws a new error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0dio.png)

Somehow my app is getting in conflict with Firebase, and even if I upload the dist folder contents to another hosting provider, and not host it with firebase, it still shows the same errors.

I tried commenting out the db connections in my components and the html and css work just fine. But when I try to connect to the database I get these errors.